# How effective is it to trim white space while lexing

Tags: ruby, compiler-construction, lex

I'm experimenting making a toy lexer in ruby. I have a list of tokens

```
  TOKEN_TYPE = [
    [:fn, /\bfn\b/],
    [:identifier, /\b[a-zA-Z]+\b/],
    [:o_bracket, /\[/],
    [:c_bracket, /\]/],
    [:integer, /\b[0-9]\b/],
    [:semi_col, /;/],
    [:plus, /\+/],
    [:minus, /-/],
    [:equals, /=/]
  ]
```

In side my tokenizer class I have two functions parsing the string

```
def tokenize
    tokens = []
    until @code.empty?
      tokens << tokenize_one
      @code = @code.strip
    end
    tokens
  end

  def tokenize_one
    TokenTypes::TOKEN_TYPE.each do |type, re|
      re = /\A(#{re})/
      if @code =~ re
        value = $1
        @code = @code[value.length..-1]
        return Token.new(type, value)
      end
    end
    raise RuntimeError.new(
      "Can't match token on #{@code.inspect}"
    )
  end
```

My question is, is it really effective to use `.strip` for removing white space out of the truncated code. Would it be better to write a regex for ignoring the white space, or are there other faster / efficient methods for this? I was thinking about splitting @code on white space then parsing that. I'm not too sure how effective that is.

Comment: If you are writing a lexer then do not use regular expressions. That is like building an engine out of tens of small engines, it is just an added layer of complexity. You should get a book on compiler design and work through the first few chapters. Also after many years of writing parsers I have to come to learn when to just skip the lexer and parse everything in a single pass. I prefer DCGs but few people venture into that realm much less need them for parsing.

Comment: Besides already mentioned regexps I would worry much more about this line's performance impact - `@code = @code[value.length..-1]` - it looks like you're copying potentially large data many times...

Comment: @GuyCoder Any recommended books?

Comment: @KonstantinStrukov Yeah I see that now. I was trying to get rid on the last string that was being tokenized

Comment: *Any recommended books?*  The one I personally have and use is Compilers: Principles, Techniques, and Tools ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilers:_Principles,_Techniques,_and_Tools)) ([WorldCat](https://www.worldcat.org/title/compilers-principles-techniques-and-tools/oclc/1055658673)) It is also known as the [Dragon Book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragon_Book)

Comment: If you are impatient this is not the book for you. But then learning how to code parsing correctly is not something for the impatient, it takes time reading the book(s) doing the exercises and making many awful mistake over the years.

Comment: The book does not cover DCGs, I had to literally figure those out on my own. My other problem with DCGs is the way I do them, and some others with lots of experience with them, it is not the way software libraries do them so we have to make my own libraries for them. However with DCGs I can typically do all of that in a hour or two for large sets of grammar rules. The debugging is what takes time as often there is no formal grammar for what I parse.